# The CD application using DBM from begining linux programming book

Tags: c, linux

The confusion is from book Beginning `Linux` Programming by Neil Mathew and Richard Stones.

In the book using `DBM` they have taught how to bulid a `CD` application to store `CD` data.
They have used two `structs` one for storing `CD` catalog entry and one for storing `CD` tracks entry.The `structs` are as below:

```
/* The catalog table */
#define CAT_CAT_LEN 30
#define CAT_TITLE_LEN 70
#define CAT_TYPE_LEN 30
#define CAT_ARTIST_LEN 70

typedef struct {
char catalog[CAT_CAT_LEN + 1];
char title[CAT_TITLE_LEN + 1];
char type[CAT_TYPE_LEN + 1];
char artist[CAT_ARTIST_LEN + 1];
} cdc_entry;

/* The tracks table, one entry per track */
#define TRACK_CAT_LEN CAT_CAT_LEN
#define TRACK_TTEXT_LEN 70
typedef struct {
char catalog[TRACK_CAT_LEN + 1];
int track_no;
char track_txt[TRACK_TTEXT_LEN + 1];
} cdt_entry;
```

Not exactly getting what a:

```
char catalog[CAT_CAT_LEN];
```

is meant for in cdc_entry structure
As i thought earlier user will type name of the album in that field but title is there for that. Then what catalog field is meant for actually not getting.
What i think of various fileds can have is:

title = name of the album(Reckless)

type = is like genere (POP, ROCK, HIPHOP)

artist = who sang the song (Bryan adams)

catalog = ?(for what this field)

If anyone has been through this book and got what this field(catalog) should actually store.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why does it matter? Without access to the rest of the code, we can only speculate, but a typical use would be for the first field to contain a unique identifier for each record, so that you can disambiguate duplicates, for example.

Comment: @TheMask nothing technical in this just wanted to know what is the puprose of using catalog variable.